Beginner Project on Simulating Quantum Dots for Qubits – Recommended Resources and Software
I’m interested in starting a project to simulate quantum dots for qubit applications, namely exploring coupled quantum dots for two-qubit gates. (You can suggest me other similar projects too). While I have some familiarity with quantum computing and qubits, I’m new to the concept of quantum dots.
Here’s what I’ve studied so far on semiconductors:

Principles of Electronic Materials and Devices (4th Edition) by Safa O. Kasap
Semiconductor Physics and Devices: Basic Principles (4th Edition) by Donald A. Neamen, up to the homojunction section (included).

Could anyone suggest additional foundational topics or resources (books, papers, etc.) that would be helpful to get started? Also, what simulation software would be recommended for modeling quantum dots in this context?
Thank you for any guidance on getting started with this project! BTW, I am doing undergrad in Electrical and Electronics, if that matters.

I wouldn't think it a full answer but a basic/introductory QM textbook seems quite vital.

@controlgroup I did read a book on QM, the Introduction to quantum mechanics by David J. Griffiths. I should have mentioned it too.
